# BI Publisher prints '?' instead of Euro symbol

Tags: bi-publisher

I have registered a concurrent program that uses RDF as the data source and a BI RTF template for layout. It works fine except that the output does not display the Euro symbol correctly (it displays a '?' instead).Some forums suggested changing the encoding of the RDF output to iso-8859-15. I tried this but the Euro symbol still doesn't display correctly (some other unreadable character is printed). It looks there is some font issue but I'm not able to find any clear instructions on how to change the font settings on the application side. Please advise.
(The Euro symbol is part of a database column value, I cannot hardcode it in the RTF directly)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you create your RTF template. If you are using [BI Publisher Desktop](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/xmlpclient-082400.html), you can use Word to set the font of the field which would display the Euro sign in PDF. I've tested that Arial works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Euro Symbol is Displayed as Question Mark '?' in XML Publisher Report (Doc ID 387698.1) should be the solution

Answer (score 0):

Try the format-currency function.

```
<?format-currency:AMOUNT;CURRENCY;'true'?>
```

Where **AMOUNT** is the value like **0.00**

Where **CURRENCY** is the currency code like **USD**